# How do I properly access my MainActivity from outside its class?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, variables, android-activity

I have a function of which I call from MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    doSomethingFunction(this)
}
```

...

```
doSomethingFunction(activity: AppCompatActivity)
{
    var button = activity.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    // if I try do something with button the app crashes eg
    button.text = "Text"
}
```

Which leads me to believe somehow I must not be accessing activity from MainActivity and `activity.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)` didn't actually return my buttons id thats why its crashing. I tried to extend `doSomethingFunction(activity: MainActivity)` but it crashes the same.

How do I properly pass "MainActivity" to doSomethingFunction so that I can do stuff with "activity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a `setContentView` so yes, it will crash, because there's no layout associated with this activity.

you have to use setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutHere) in order for you to be able to access xml components.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.something)
    doSomethingFunction(this)
}
```

Comment: Just looked at the logs and surely enough its saying button is null. so what do I do?

Comment: it's null because it can't find the button, because you don't use setContentView

Comment: I tried that its still saying button is null.

Comment: it's impossible to answer you further without giving enough information to recreate the problem. from what you've posted your mistake was not setting a layout, so that's what i've answered. you can update your question to include your xml and i'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: feel free to comment here when you've updated your question and i'll try my best to give you an answer

Comment: firstly my problem was i was calling doSomething before setContentView...and I created a simple test project and everything in it works fine. I will investigate and try to recreate the problem with facebook button and see where the error is cropping up from

Answer (score 0):

[a_local_nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729721/a-local-nobody) answered my question correctly. I am just posting so that others may benefit. The are two reasons I was facing that error

- Reason 1

Just as my code denotes I was calling `doSomethingFunction(this)` before `setContentView` thats why there was no setContentView in my sample code. So I couldn't access members in MainActivity well

This lead me to believe in my own project I wasn't initialising my button in time. So After investigations the culprit is in the xml of which [a_local_nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729721/a-local-nobody) encouraged me to post. I couldn't do that because it was a complex project and I didn't know which part of the xml.

- Reason 2

I was using drawer layout which was in turn loading a layout with my button

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_with_button">
```

This was causing a delay and at run time the button would be null so the app was crashing.
I put the button as a child of Drawer layout and the app runs fine. I deleted <s>app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_with_button"</s>

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
<Button/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```